# What is the correct type of std::fixed, std::scientific etc.. in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to put `std::fixed`, `std::scientific` etc... to a variable, but can't figure out how. I am trying this code, but it doesn't work:

```
typedef std::vector<std::ios_base> FlagArray;

int main() {
    FlagArray tmp1 = { std::fixed, std::scientific };
    FlagArray tmp2 = { std::internal, std::right, std::left };
    FlagArray tmp3 = { std::uppercase, std::showbase, std::showpoint, std::showpos };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of these manipulators is `std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &str)`. They are functions.

It means, you need to use `std::vector<std::ios_base &(*)(std::ios_base &str)> FlagArray;`.

---

Here is how your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ios>

typedef std::vector<std::ios_base &(*)(std::ios_base &str)> FlagArray;

int main() {
    FlagArray tmp1 = {std::fixed,std::scientific};
    FlagArray tmp2 = {std::internal,std::right,std::left};
    FlagArray tmp3 = {std::uppercase,std::showbase,std::showpoint,std::showpos};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `std::function<std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)>`

Comment: @myaut I see no reason to use it when usual pointer is enough.

Comment: @myaut: You won't be able to `operator<<` a `std::function<...>` with a stream. The overload is for function pointers only.